# How to generate a heat map of rental in jupyter notebook using ipyleaflet?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, location, heatmap, ipyleaflet

I am working on a dataset containing the rents of buildings in Paris by neighborhood and also the gps coordinates.
I would like to make a heat map of the rents using the geographical coordinates of my dataset.
[image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfE7w.png)

Any idea how to proceed?

I tried this code but it don't work :

```
from ipyleaflet import Map, Heatmap
from random import uniform

center = (48.856614, 2.3522219) #we place the center of the map on the gps coordinates of Paris(city)
m = Map(center=center, zoom=12)


heatmap = Heatmap(
    locations=[df['geo_point_2d']], #we get the gps coordinates of the 'geo_point_2d' column in df
    radius=20
)

m.add_layer(heatmap);

m
```

I'm a beginner with Jupiter Notebook...

Thank you for your help !

Julien